# Proof for a conjecture based on roots of unity

Tags: number-theory, complex-numbers

let $n = pq$ (prime factorization of n)

let the set $X_n = {\{\omega,\omega^2, \cdots, \omega^n\}}$ the set of $nth$ roots of unity. It can simply be deduced that the sets $X_p$ and $X_q$ are subsets of $X_n$

Conjecture: The set of $kth$ roots of unity with $k\leq n$ denoted by $X_k$ is a subset of $X_n$ if and only if both $k$ and $n-k$ can be expressed as linear combinations of prime factors of $n$

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: $X_k$ is a subset of $X_n$ means $e^{2i \pi /k} = e^{2i \pi a/n}$ which means $a/n-1/k \in \Bbb{Z}$ which means $k | n$. What do you mean exactly with " linear combination of prime factors " ? Do you realize any integer $\ge 2$ is of the form $2a+3b$ ?